# a4j:support not working on chrome

Tags: google-chrome, jsf, ajax4jsf

This is my code.

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.value}" valueChangeListener="#{bean.valueChanged}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.values}" />
    <a4j:support event="onchange" reRender="beanForm" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Within the form there other components as well. When using FireFox, the form is re-rednered smoothly. But on chrome, it seems as the page just gets reloaded as the scroll bar scrolls to the top.
Is that a known issue?

Thanks

Comment: When anything appears to be failing in client side, please **always** look in browser's console and HTTP traffic monitor for clues and abnormalities and explicitly mention it in the question. Press F12 in browser to get there.

Comment: and always mention version info as much as possible. So jsf, ajax4jsf, but also browser etc...